# What extractly mat3(a mat4 matrix) statement in glsl do?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm doing a per fragment lighting and when correcting normal vecter, i got this code: `vec3 f_normal = mat3(MVI) * normal;` Where MVI is: `mat4 MVI = transpose(inverse(ModelViewMatrix));`. So what is return after `mat3(MVI)` statement?

Comment: Well, simple reasoning (and just a small understanding of the mathematical basics of computer graphics) dictates that it's the upper left 3x3 part. Besides that, by all means don't transpose and invert your matrix in the shader. It doesn't change per-vertex and can be done on the CPU (where it doesn't take any longer for a single matrix).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
mat3(MVI) * normal
```

Returns the upper 3x3 matrix from the 4x4 matrix and multiplies the normal by that. This matrix is called the 'normal matrix'. You use this to bring your normals from world space to eye space. The upper 3x3 portion of the matrix is important for scale and rotation, while the rest is only for translation (and normals are never translated)

To take a normal from world space to eye space, you just need the 3x3  **inverse transpose** of the model view matrix. Unless your matrix in othro normal (no non-uniform scale) in that case the original matrix is the same as its inverse transpose.

Comment: Using the upper 3x3 of the modelview matrix only works when there are no non-uniform scales, otherwise you have to use the transpose of the inverse of the modelview (which is a 4x4 matrix).  Note that you have to set the w-component of the normal to zero when multiplying by a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @racarate correct. I'll amend my answer to avoid people getting the wrong idea.

Answer (score 3):

From [GLSL types](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Types#Matrix_constructors): *"There are no restrictions on size when doing matrix construction from another matrix. So you can construct a 4x2 matrix from a 2x4 matrix; only the corresponding elements are copied."*. So, you get the MVI's top-left 3x3 submatrix as a result.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, so does it affects to final result? (why doesn't it use fourth element in normals vector but remove some elements on MVI?)

Comment: It's a generic operation and does not know anything about the semantics of the underlying matrix being operated on.